# Jmeter - Variable not evaluated properly

Tags: java, testing, jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing

I am using following syntax to get value but it is not working , same expression working for a HTTP request but not working for another.

```
${__V(STU_IDsub${index})}
```

I am evaluating this value in a while loop

`'index'` is a counter variable

`'STU_IDsub'` is a variable having actual value

when I use this expression in HTTP Request and use 'View Results Tree' it is evaluating in 
`'STU_IDsub1'` or 'STU_IDsub2' and so on...

while actual value evaluated in DebugSampler are

`STU_IDsub1= 36, STU_IDsub2=46` and so on which are correct values, I need these `values(36,46...)` not `STU_IDsub1,STU_IDsub2`

what I am doing wrong?

what is the other way to get `'STU_IDsub'` 's nth value?